# Show as percentage of another column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a table that looks like this

```
|        Date         |  Total  |  Loss  |
|---------------------|---------|--------|
|     Jan 1 2018      |   90    |    5   |
|---------------------|---------|--------|
|     Jan 3 2018      |   10    |    5   |
|---------------------|---------|--------|
|     Feb 1 2018      |   50    |    5   |
|---------------------|---------|--------|
|     Feb 3 2018      |   50    |   10   |
|---------------------|---------|--------|
```

I wanna be able to show in a table how much percentage of "Total" "Loss" is depending on the period.

For example if in my dashboard I show the table visualizer as months, it should give :

```
|        Date         |  Loss % |
|---------------------|---------|
|      Jan 2018       |   10%   |
|---------------------|---------|
|      Feb 2018       |   15%   |
|---------------------|---------|
```

But if I show it as year, it should give :

```
|        Date         |  Loss % |
|---------------------|---------|
|        2018         |  12.5%  |
|---------------------|---------|
```

Right now the only solution I have found is to create tables in the Data tab that would sum up my main table for each Month. But that can't be a permanent solution to me (I end up with too many tables, as I have to do that kind of table for many different columns and conflicting relationships).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the same result by adding the following measure to your table `LossPercent = 100 * SUM(SalesData[Loss]) / SUM(SalesData[Total])`, then adding a relationship between the date and a Dates table, which contains a breakdown of dates into the groupings you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Loss %` measure:

```
Loss % = 
DIVIDE (
    SUM ( TableName[Loss] ),
    SUM ( TableName[Total] ),
    BLANK()
)
```

Format the measure as `percentage`