# Power BI Compute Percentage Relative to Sum of Another Column

Tags: powerbi

I have data in multiple categories (`A`, `B`, `C`) which consists of an Actual and Estimated numerical amount, as well as an error. For example:

```
Cat Est Act Err | Pct_Tot
A   3   5   2   | 0.2
B   2   2   0   | 0.0
C   1   3   2   | 0.2
```

I need to compute and plot a bar chart, by Cat, showing each error relative to the total sum of all actuals (`Err/sum(Act)`). I.e., I need to compute and plot the `Pct_Tot` column shown above. Of course, there are multiple other categories by which I need to slice & filter, so the `sum(Act)` needs to be responsive to these.

Everything I've tried thus far results in the undesired calculation of `Err/Act` because PowerBI interprets the `sum(Act)` to mean `sum(Act per Cat)`. Note that this is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53443620/show-as-percentage-of-another-column-in-power-bi); in his first dashboard example, the numerator denominator is the sum by month, while what I want is the total sum (would give 10/200 and 15/200, respectively).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate % of a total, you need to remove filters from the calculation. I will assume that your table name is "Table", and that "Cat", "Act" and "Err" are columns. Then:

```
Pct_Tot =
VAR Actual_Total = CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table[Act] ), ALL ( Table[Cat] ) )
RETURN DIVIDE( SUM(Table[Err]), Actual_Total )
```

Function ALL here tells DAX to ignore any filters for column "Cat".